# Flex 3: Embedding swf or image file in flex text area control

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to show some html in a text area control.
Is it possible to embed swfs in the html?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. But I was hoping to embed a swf instead of a gif. I hope this is possible for me to do.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer covers it. Sorry for wasting your time.
[Unable to access embedded images in htmlText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783710/flex-embeded-images-in-htmltext)