# Is there a good way to style an unordered list (loaded from XML) in Flash?

Tags: css, xml, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I'm loading the XML into a text field as htmlText.

[The `StyleSheet` class in Flash only supports a *subset* of CSS1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/text/StyleSheet.html)–which debuted in 1996!–and doesn't support `list-style-type` or `list-style-image`. I'd specifically like to substitute an image instead of the default disc for an unordered list.

If you've had success implementing a work-around, I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: It is true - flash supports only css1. There is however one thing you could try - you could loop trough all <li> and append a picture at x,y coordinates of each begining <li>.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I can think of would be to use the `<img />` tag to display your bullet images in the TextField.

You'll need to structure the HTML to simulate a list:

e.g. (Sorry about the poor formatting, it's not letting me put in the tags properly)
    < p>
        < img src="bullet" />Line 1.< br/>
        < img src="bullet" />Line 2.< br/>
    < /p>

You can see my post here for details on how to display embedded images in TextFields (both Flash and Flex):
[Unable to access embedded images in htmlText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783710/flex-embeded-images-in-htmltext/1726573#1726573)