# Flex: embedded images in TextArea appear only in top left corner

Tags: html, image, apache-flex, textarea

I managed to add embedded assets to htmlText of my TextArea like described here (Sly_cardinal's post, currently the third one):

[Unable to access embedded images in htmlText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783710/flex-embeded-images-in-htmltext)

But all the images appear in the top left corner (overlayed)!

Interesting is that the place where the images should be, is actually empty and the text wraps around it, like they were there. But they are all in the corner.

I'm using large p tags for the text and all html displays perfectly where it should be. My only problem are these images.

Hope somebody has at least an idea. Thanks.

P.D. sorry for not showing code, it's cluttered at the moment with other things. But I hope the description is enough to get some useful tips.

P.D. 2. I did a test now with exactly the same code but using normal path to png file instead of asset and that works!.

Comment: html support within Flex isn't very good. I'd recommend some other solution based upon the struggles I've had with it.

Comment: I'm using an embedded iframe for other things. But for this certain task I decided for Flex, don't need a lot of html there, besides few images. And the iframe solution doesn't integrate completly "fluent" (although it does very well, but still has some things, like having to toggle visibility each time a popup appears, layout getting distorted when the browser has zoom, etc.), so I prefer to not use it if there are not (very) good reasons.

Comment: yeah. I've had a lot of strangeness with the iframe solutions available. I was thinking more of a simplified markup converted into native components.