# htmlText in air and inline images

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, htmltext

I'm trying to add inline images to the htmlText so that they would appear like smileys for a chat conversation. Currently we use htmlText property of a TextField component, i've researched enough on it, they say Air framework ignores the <img tag if given in the htmlText property. so, I cannot use it.

Is there a way to do this kind of feature in flex? have smileys inline to the text? Can we change the htmlText property to accept the <img element?

P.S: We use all mxml components, cannot use sdk 4.6 text flow for this.

Comment: It can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783710/flex-embeded-images-in-htmltext

Comment: Thanks Anton, i've looked at the example, that example talks about the flex example, flex does not ignore the &lt;img /&rt; html tag, but Air framework does ignore it for security reasons. Is there any other way i could add image in Adobe air framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm considering textFlow for this. It can convert the htmlText into text flow format. Sounds promising.